# Dynamic TableRow in TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

Someone could tell me why my app crash?? When I add 1 tablerow everything goes right but when i try to add more than 1 table row my app crask

```
public void generaLayout(){
    TableLayout tabla = new TableLayout(this);

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        row[i] = new TableRow(this);
        tabla.addView(row[i]);
        for(int j = 0; j < contador2; j++){
            row[i].addView(textArray[j]);
        }
    }

    layout.addView(tabla);
}
public void generaTextView(int i, String cad){
    textArray[i] = new TextView(this);
    textArray[i].setText(cad);


}
```

Here is the logcat
6-14 04:13:33.814: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property 06-14 04:13:34.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3733): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-14 04:13:34.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3733): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. 06-14 04:13:34.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3733): at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3131)

Comment: can you please post the logcat, the thing I'm thinking it might be at the moment is the textArray[j] is not set so you might be getting a null pointer exception

Comment: hey i put the complete code, please help me

Comment: can you please post the logcat. It will detail the actual error that is happening. You can see it in eclipse under window-> show view->other select android-> logcat double click that and you will get a new window that will show the errors you are getting.

Comment: I dont know how!!! there a lot of orange text in my logcat :(

Comment: You can highlight the rows, then Ctrl + C to copy it. If it's crashing, there should be a bunch of red lines.

Comment: 06-14 04:13:33.814: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-14 04:13:34.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3733): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 04:13:34.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3733): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.


06-14 04:13:34.714: E/AndroidRuntime(3733):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3131)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based off that log.

I think it is because you are adding the same TextView to different rows causing "The specified child already has a parent". E.g You are adding textArray[0] To row's 0, and 1. Row 1 it would crash as that textview is already associated with row 0.

You currently have a one dimensional TextView Array. and you are using that same array for each row.

If you want to store them, you are going to have to use a 2D array.
E.g
textArray[i][j]

Your generate would have to change to

```
public void generaTextView(int i, int j, String cad){
    textArray[i][j] = new TextView(this);
    textArray[i][j].setText(cad);


}
```

You would also have to change this

```
row[i].addView(textArray[j]);
```

to

```
row[i].addView(textArray[i][j]);
```